# "shared library 'RSQLite' not found" when loading RSQLite in Portable-R

Tags: r

As title, I have no idea why I receive this error message when I am trying to use the RSQLite Library by `library(RSQLite)`, suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Look in the directory if the shared library is actually there. Portable-R is Windows, right?

Comment: yes, portable-R is windows, and I can find the library folder inside R, but still the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved, the `RSQLite.dll` file is stored inside the i386 folder inside the libs folder, causing this problem, just move the dll file out of the i386 folder will do